# Latex question “Missing $ inserted

Tags: equations

I want to write this simple equation in latex

```
    2/|w|
```

In which |w| is the norm of w,,

I tried with

```
     \frac{2}{\|w\|}
```

And get error "Missing $ inserted"

then I use this

```
  \frac{2}{$\|w\|$}
```

And still get same error..

Does someone know how to solve this problem??

Comment: `\frac` is a math command so `$\frac{2}{\|w\|}$`

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to include the whole thing in a math environment, as `\frac` is a math command.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[width=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

Inline: $ \frac{2}{\|w\|}$ \\[2em]

Display:
\[ \frac{2}{\|w\|} \]

Numbered Display:
\begin{equation} \frac{2}{\|w\|} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: formulas]